# MySQL join and count according to its column value

Tags: mysql

If I have a MySQL table looking something like this:

`breeds`

```
id      name
-------------------------------
1       Labrador
2       Jack Russel Terrier
3       Shetland Sheepdog
```

And a MySQL table looking like this:

`dogs`

```
id      owner       breed    sex
-----------------------------------
1       Sara        1        f
2       Kent        1        f
3       Billy       1        m
4       Joe         2        f
5       Billy       2        m
```

Is it possible to run a MySQL query to get output like this:

```
id      name                  females   males
------------------------------------------------
1       Labrador              2         1
2       Jack Russel Terrier   1         1
3       Shetland Sheepdog     0         0
```

I would like to have a JOIN or similar that count the number of females/males from the dogs table.

Comment: My comment is off topic letting someone else to gather points. But i suggest u normalize data in dogs.owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT b.id,b.name,
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sex='f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as females,
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sex='m' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as males
FROM breeds b LEFT JOIN
     dogs d on b.id=d.breed
GROUP BY b.id,b.name
```

**Explanation:**

using `LEFT JOIN` will include the record eventhough there is male/female count. `IFNULL` will replace the null value with 0.

Result:

```
id  name                females males
-------------------------------------
1   Labrador            2       1
2   Jack Russel Terrier 1       1
3   Shetland Sheepdog   0       0
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c7381/1).

Comment: Thank you for the solution and a nice description on what the query does, this seems to working great!

Comment: @Raging_Bull I have a follow up question that you hopefully can help me with? how can I `ORDER BY females+males` ? Thanks alot!

Comment: See [**this link**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c7381/1) for order by males+females.

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT id, name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dogs WHERE breed=b.id AND sex='f') females,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dogs WHERE breed=b.id AND sex='m') males
FROM breeds b
```

see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03da0/1